# hadoop choose input file among input folder

Tags: java, hadoop

In `training_set` folder, file exist like this

```
mv_000000
mv_000001
mv_000002
...
```

The index is the movie id that can be found on `movie_title.txt`

`movie_title.tx` file is like:

```
1,2003,Dinosaur Planet
2,2004,Isle of Man TT 2004 Review
3,1997,Character   
4,1994,Paula Abdul's Get Up & Dance
5,2004,The Rise and Fall of ECW 
...
```

The fist column is the index of a specific movie name.

I practice hadoop base on netplix prize contest data set. 
I assume that I insert specific movie title such as "Sick".
Then go to `movie_titles.txt` file and search moive title id of "sick".
Finally set input path movie title id.

For example, if I start hadoop program as:

```
hadoop jar ~ [input path] [output path] [moiveA name]
```

than must set input path `training_set/mv_movieAIndex`.

As I say, information of movie id exist on `movie_title.txt`.

Please give me a little hint to figure out this problem.

Comment: what's your end goal? i mean what you are exepcting post Map red as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement doesn't seem to be related to `Hadoop` at all. All you need is a lookup for the `id` against the movieName specified by the 3rd parameter of the `hadoop jar` command. The following snippet will get the job done :

```
private static Map<String, Integer> getMovieMappings(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> movieMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] temp = line.split(",");
            movieMap.put(temp[2].trim(), Integer.parseInt(temp[0].trim()));
        }
    } finally {
        if (br != null)   br.close(); 
    }
    return movieMap;
}
```

Now in driver, just get the map and set the inputPath accordingly :

```
Map<String, Integer> movieMap = getMovieMappings("/pathTo/movie_title.txt");
int movieId = movieMap.get(args[2]);
System.out.println(String.format("mv_%06d", movieId));
FileInputFormat.addInputPath( job, 
                              new Path( "training_set",
                                        String.format("mv_%06d", movieId)));
```

May it helps.